# does useloaderdata() in react-router resolve promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-router

```
<Route index element={<BlogPostsPage />} loader={blogPostLoader} />
```

BlogPage

```
function BlogPostsPage() {
  const posts = useLoaderData() 

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Our Blog Posts</h1>

      <Posts blogPosts={posts} />
    </>
  );
}

export function loader () {
  return getPosts() 
}
```

getPosts()

```
export async function getPosts() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw { message: 'Failed to fetch posts.', status: 500 };
  }
  
  return response.json();
}
```

My main doubt, since we are returning a promise in a loader function, does `useLoaderData()` resolve it for us since we aren't awaiting for the data?

It's a doubt which I have.

Answer (score 2):

The `useLoaderData` hook isn't resolving any Promise returned from a loader function, it's simply returns the (*already resolved*) value returned from a loader function.

> Each route can define a "loader" function to provide data to the route
> element ***before it renders***. (*emphasis mine*)

The `loader` is called prior to the route (and `element` component) being rendered so by the time the route is rendered, any Promises have already been settled. In other words... all the "awaiting" is done in the loader function and router, the component gets mounted/rendered the the data is immediately available in the component.

Comment: as you say all the "awaiting" is done in the loader function, how you can manage loading state if something is taking too much time to load? If you want to add loading spinner and you are performing the fetch inside the loader, how you will communicate that with components so they can load the spinner?

Comment: @BorislavStefanov I saw your post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77328594/8690857) and wondered if what you were really trying to do is to use [deferred loading](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred). That post has been closed as duplicate and it looks like you may have voted to reopen. Let's discuss in that post.

Comment: To be honest, I tried it but every time I receive the result immediate and I don't see if there is something being loading. I tried to add await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); to resolve function and then for 3 seconds page is not loading and then continue. Maybe this isn't the right approach to test?

Comment: @BorislavStefanov It could be your browser is "smart" and immediately returning a cached result because it recognized the duplicate request, but let's please discuss this loading question in your post.

Comment: I am trying to see if "something is being loading" so I can render loading spinner. I use global context to manage loading state but I don't mind to do it in other way. Just simply I want to know if there is possible way to know if something is being fetching in loader function so I can prepare Loading spinner for example

Comment: @BorislavStefanov Yes, there is. You can pass in the context value like the duplicate shows and the loader function can call `setIsLoading` and somewhere higher in the ReactTree than the router you can render some loading UI, ***or*** you can use deferred loading and display the loading UI right in the `Profile` component (*something like [this](/a/76963519/8690857)*).

Answer (score 1):

`useLoaderData` does not initiate a fetch. It simply reads the result of a fetch React Router manages internally, so you don't need to worry about it refetching when it re-renders for reasons outside of routing.

You can find more details at: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data