# How to pass Context to React-Router-6's loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I am using Context to manage my global loading state and React-router-6 for my router. I choose the approach to use loader functionality and to have my API requests for page loading in it. The problem is that I cannot access my Global Context status to change it in the loader functions simply because useGlobalContext expects to be used in function components. Here is my MainRouter:

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home, homeLoader } from "../pages/Home";
import { Profile, profileLoader } from "../pages/Profile";
import MenuBar from "../components/MenuBar";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalContext";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <MenuBar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
        loader: homeLoader,
      },
     //many other routes here.....
      {
        path: "/profile",
        element: <Profile />,
        loader: profileLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const MainRouter = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default MainRouter;
```

My GlobalContext:

```
import {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  ReactNode,
} from "react";

interface GlobalContextValue {
  isLoading: boolean;
  setIsLoading: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

// Create the Context with the default value
const GlobalContext = createContext<GlobalContextValue>({
  isLoading: false,
  setIsLoading: () => {},

});

export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);

export const GlobalProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoading,
        setIsLoading,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And I wrap around the App:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalProvider>
        <MainRouter />
      </GlobalProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is how to access **setIsLoading** in the **profileLoader** function as there is my fetching logic? The simplies solution is to change logic and to use useEffect to fetch the data inside profile component but I want to be able to use the loader function for initial fetching. How I can do that? Here is the Profile:

```
import React from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { getUserById } from "../db/utils/userUtil";
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalContext";

const Profile = () => {
  const profile = useLoaderData();
  return <div>Profile</div>;
};
const profileLoader = async () => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const result = await getUserById(user?.email);
  console.log(result);
  if (result) return result;
  return null;
};

export { Profile, profileLoader };
```

This is working perfectly fine but I cannot change the loading state now. If I use

```
const {setIsLoading} = useGlobalContext()
```

inside profileLoader it will reteurn me error that it is not used in functional component.

Comment: You can't directly call useGlobalContext inside profileLoader since it's not a functional component. Instead, you can pass a callback to profileLoader from your functional component, which can then update the loading state in the global context.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know I can't use it directly there. How it is possbile to send it from Profile to profileLoader?

Comment: FWIW by the time the loader function completes and `Profile` is rendered with the loaded data, it's too late for `Profile` to render any loading UI, the data was already fetched and loaded. Are you trying to show some loading UI while the route is being loaded? As-is your question is still a duplicate based on the request to "access a React context in route loader". Perhaps you have a slightly *different* request than the one you've described in your post. If the duplicate doesn't address what you are really trying to do then please [edit] the current post to explain why it's not duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

Here's how you can achieve this:

**UPDATED CODE :**
Update your Profile component to use React Router 6's  component for data loading:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { getUserById } from "../db/utils/userUtil";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Profile = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      const result = await getUserById(user?.email);
      console.log(result);
      if (result) {
        // Update your component state here with the fetched data if needed
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <div>Profile</div>;
};

export { Profile };
```

Update your routing setup to use the  component:

```
import { createBrowserRouter, Outlet, Match } from "react-router-dom";
import { Profile } from "../pages/Profile";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalContext";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <MenuBar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/profile",
        element: <Match when={() => <Profile />} />,
      },
      // other routes
    ],
  },
]);

const MainRouter = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default MainRouter;
```

With this setup, the  component allows you to conditionally render your Profile component based on data loading. You can use the useEffect hook within the Profile component to fetch data, and once the data is fetched, it will render the Profile component with the loaded data. This approach leverages the flexibility and simplicity of React Router 6 to handle data loading and rendering

Comment: How do you use the advantage of having React-router-dom 6 here? If this is the case I would remove loader function and use the useEffect hook as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: You are correct; React Router 6 introduces new ways to handle data fetching and rendering with its <RouterProvider> and <Match> components. If you want to take advantage of React Router 6, you can handle data loading with the <Match> component and use the useEffect hook as you mentioned.  I will update the code now.

Comment: Still don't see how this resolves the issue with fetching in loader function and setting the loading state.

Comment: I know the React-Router documentation is pretty bad in some areas, but what is this `Match` component? There's no mention of it in the docs nor anywhere in the repo, nor is it available as an export to be imported.